# Split Linked list

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I kinda need some help in the **frontBackSplitLinkedList** part,

For example, assume that given linked list is: 2 6 7 8 9
The resulting front and back are:
front: 2 6 7
back: 8 9

I've searched through some websites but most of the codings are using nodes instead of linked list.

Any idea how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Nodes are what _make up_ the linked list in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually have to count elements in list, as far as i see it, you store the number of elements in _linkedlist. You can always use that value to split however you like. I would strongly suggest to first simlify your List, so it can add elements only to the back or the front of the List, it will be easier to work with it, but won't really affect the principle of split function.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correcly then you want to split the list in the middle, where un uneven list will be split a frontlist that is one larger than the backlist.

First of all you must have a count of the list length. I propose that you walk the list, counting the number of list nodes.

Then you divide that number as follows:

```
count = (count+1)/2;
```

Now we need to know if you must create two new lists (so you have to make copies of all the list nodes), or whether the old list may be reused. Assume it may be reused, then you assign the old list to `frontlist`, walk `count` listnodes, asign that one to `backlist` and set the `next` member of the one before it to `NULL`.

You are done now, except that the caller may no longer use the original list (it has become equivalent, and actually is, `frontlist`).

Comment: The code shows that size is being maintained for the linked list so there is no reason to "walk the list, counting the number of list nodes". You also need to update this value as part of the split.